# three radio buttons were picked at the same time in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button and three radio buttons and a label.When I choose one of the radios and click the button,I want to see a label containing a sentence. My problem is that I can choose three of these radio buttons at the same time.How can I get rid of this action?Here is my code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            Label5.Text = txtName1.Text + txtCodePers.Text + txtMoavenat1.Text; 
           
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            Label5.Text = txtName2.Text + txtCodePers.Text + txtMoavenat2.Text;
        }
        if (RadioButton3.Checked)
        {
            Label5.Text = txtName3.Text + txtCodePers.Text + txtMoavenat3.Text;
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to append string for `Label5.Text` for this case. From your code, your `Label5.Text` is re-assigned value if the condition meets, hence this is not working when you have 2 or more checkboxes checked.

Comment: Could you please explain more or write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `GroupName` of each of three radio buttons to be the same, so that they are in the same 'group'. Then you will only be able to select one of them at a time. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname?view=netframework-4.8#system-web-ui-webcontrols-radiobutton-groupname

Comment: And, perhaps even better is to use a RadioButtion list, and then it even supports databinding and a source from a database.